# Create CSS grid layout

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to create a layout using CSS grid like in the image below for resolutions above 900px:-

[image]

For resolutions below 900px I need the layout to look like this 
[image]

So, far I have tried this :-

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 250px auto 250px;
   grid-column-gap: 1rem;
 }
```

Above code creates image 1, but I am not able to change it to accommodate layout changes for below 900px (image2).

How to create this layout in CSS grid so that it creates layout as mentioned in image above?

you can find my code here:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8th174ew/6/)

Comment: Have you looked into media queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Could  you may be please give me an example using css grid. I know media queries may be useful but how to change the order of elements

Comment: Check out this first: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I have read through it, but I am not able to make layout as in image. checkout my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8th174ew/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grid-template-areas` should be easier to use

```css
.item1 { grid-area: box1; }
.item2 { grid-area: box2; }
.item3 { grid-area: list; }
.item4 { grid-area: box3; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'box1 list box3'
    'box2 list box3';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .grid-container {
      grid-template-areas:
        'box1 list'
        'box2 list'
        'box3 list';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="item3">List</div>  
  <div class="item4">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope we can use **grid-column-start**, **grid-column-end**, **grid-row-start** and **grid-row-end** to achive required grids along with **media**.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.box2{
  grid-column-start:1;
  grid-column-end:2;
}
.list1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start:2;
  grid-column-end:3;
}
.box3{
 grid-column-start:3;
 grid-column-end:4;
 grid-row-start:1;
 grid-row-end:2;
}

@media (max-width:900px){
    .grid-container {
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    }
    .list1 {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 4;
    }
   .box3{
    grid-column-start:1;
    grid-column-end:2;
    grid-row-start:3;
    grid-row-end:4;
    }
 
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Lines</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="box1">1</div>
  <div class="box2">2</div>
  <div class="list1">3</div>  
  <div class="box3">4</div>  
</div>

<p>You can refer to line numbers when placing grid items.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope **grid-auto-flow: column** will help along with **mediaquery**

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/16ojq7yz/3/)

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="item2">List</div>
  <div class="item3">Box 2</div> 
  <div class="item4">Box 3</div>
</div>


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;

  > div {
    border: solid 1px #00f;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

.item2 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end:   3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { 
  .grid-container { 
    grid-template-columns: 25% 1fr ;
  }

.item2 {
    grid-row-end: 4;  
  }
}
```