# How to change the grid layout to 4x4 with a 1x1 on the right?

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding and working on making a contact page like this: Picture:
[image]

I have figured out how to do my grids, but not so it is either 4x4 on one side and 1x1 on the other side like the picture, or if it is a way to modify the grid so I don't need to split it into two separate grids.

Can anyone help?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

html {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: ;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

.grid_container_4 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid_container_4 div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding-top: ;
  text-align: left;
}

.grid_container_5 {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
<div class="grid_container_4">
  <div class="what_1">
    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
    <h2>Testing</h2>

  </div>

  <div class="what_2">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler"></i>
    <h2>Testing</h2>

  </div>

  <div class="what_3">
    <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
    <h2>Testing</h2>

  </div>

  <div class="what_4">
    <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
    <h2>Testing</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid_container_5">
  <div class="Testing">
    <iframe </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49732094/17175441

Comment: @steve356 You surely mean 2x2 Grid, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put them all into the same grid.

One way of doing this is to use grid-template-areas. You can tell the grid to layout like this:

```
grid-template-areas:
  'A B E E'
  'C D E E'
```

and then tell each element which area it is to occupy e.g. `grid-area: A;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: ;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .grid_container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-areas: 'A B E E' 'C D E E';
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .grid_container div {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px;
      border-style: solid;
      padding-top: ;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .grid_container div:nth-child(1) {
      grid-area: A;
    }
    
    .grid_container div:nth-child(2) {
      grid-area: B;
    }
    
    .grid_container div:nth-child(3) {
      grid-area: C;
    }
    
    .grid_container div:nth-child(4) {
      grid-area: D;
    }
    
    .grid_container div:nth-child(5) {
      grid-area: E;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid_container">
    <div class="what_1">
      <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
      <h2>Testing</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="what_2">
      <i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler"></i>
      <h2>Testing</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="what_3">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
      <h2>Testing</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="what_4">
      <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
      <h2>Testing</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="Testing">
      <iframe </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!! But how do i make this responsive?

Comment: In what way is it non responsive? You have set a max width in px bit otherwise it should change with viewport. Let me know what the problem is.

Comment: I did not try with vp but I was able to fix it buy putting in 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' in media query!

Comment: Ah, I see - yes that's fine to make everything into one long column on narrow devices.

Answer (score 0):

Grid can be taken. I would go back to the flex system here. Less CSS for the same result. Here is the desired skeleton.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 50%
}

.right {
  background-color: #333;  
  color: white;
}
.left {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;  
  background-color: #999;
}

.left-item {
  display: flex; 
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);  
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-item">1</div>
    <div class="left-item">2</div>
    <div class="left-item">3</div>
    <div class="left-item">4</div>

  </div>
  <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```